# How come hair particles don't show in render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I made a little person, I gave her particle hair and when I was done I joined everything together.

I appended her into a new scene I was making, now the hair won't show. Is there a reason for this?

The grass is also hair particles too, emitter is checked, the girl was made in Blender Render and so is the scene. What should I do?

This one is in scene mode, the next one is in rendered mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you detail or show your particle settings? if posting an image please, make bigger if you wish others to understand...

Comment: Are the original file and the file you appended it into using the same render engine? A cycles material will not show in BI.

Comment: Also if you are still in Particle Edit mode - nothing will show in Render